# MySQL - Duplicate columns after using Join operator

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, operator-keyword

As stated in the title, I'm getting duplicate columns with this `JOIN` query.
A few tables are given and I want to write select statements to get only
the information from the tables which are needed.

Here is my SQL code so far:

```
    SELECT mitarbeiter.PNR, pfleger.PNR, Name
    from pfleger
    JOIN mitarbeiter on (mitarbeiter.PNR=pfleger.PNR)
    where Ort='Frankfurt';
```

After executing, I get the following result:

[image: MySQL table]

You can see the problem: I have two PNR columns which I don't want to have.
How can I remove the duplicate? I have tried `SELECT DISTINCT ...` but it doesn't accomplish my goal.

Comment: if you know that `mitarbeiter.pnr=pfleger.pnr` based on joins, then you only need to return one of the two in the select; as they will always be equal.

Answer (score 0):

In the `select` portion of the statement reference the `PNR` column from either of the tables (mitarbeiter, pfleger), but not both:

```
SELECT 
  mitarbeiter.PNR, 
  Name 
from pfleger JOIN mitarbeiter on (mitarbeiter.PNR=pfleger.PNR) 
where Ort='Frankfurt';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove one from the select:

```
SELECT mitarbeiter.PNR, Name from pfleger JOIN mitarbeiter on (mitarbeiter.PNR=pfleger.PNR) where Ort='Frankfurt';
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct applies to rows, not columns.  In the column list, just select one of the PNR columns:

```
SELECT mitarbeiter.PNR, Name from pfleger JOIN mitarbeiter on (mitarbeiter.PNR=pfleger.PNR) where Ort='Frankfurt';
```

Answer (score 0):

As other users have already mentioned, you just need to remove a field name from the `SELECT` clause. I just want to add that if the field you join on has the same name in both tables you can use special syntax, which allows to reference both columns as a single one:

```
SELECT PNR, Name
from pfleger
JOIN mitarbeiter USING (PNR)
where Ort='Frankfurt';
```