# MySQL - More Join operators, more aliases and Error 1066

Tags: mysql, join, operator-keyword, mysql-error-1066

Hopefully you are going to help me again :)

Well, the problem that I have is similar to the one which I've posted yesterday, but it is extended.

We are given three tables:

[image: Table: pfleger]
Pfleger

[image: Table: station]
Station

[image: Table: mitarbeiter]
Mitarbeiter

As states above, this problem is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277033/mysql-duplicate-columns-after-using-join-operator/) problem.

What was the result? Well, I get back a table with the ID's and names of the workers who are living in Frankfurt.

Now I should additionally get back the ID'S and names of the workers who are living in Frankfurt AND working in the station called Onkologie.

How should I do this?

My code so far:

```
SELECT pfleger.PNR, Name
from mitarbeiter, ...
JOIN pfleger on (mitarbeiter.PNR=pfleger.PNR)
JOIN ...
where Ort='Frankfurt' and Name='Onkologie'
```

I don't know how to make 2nd JOIN.

Comment: Where do we get "frankfurt" I don't see it in the tables listed or sample data.  and from the notation the from mitarbeiter, with `join` syntax is invalid.  you can't mix ANSI 92 standards with prior verion standards.  (either use `INNER/OUTER` join syntax or `,` between table names but not both)  in what table is 'ORT'? I don't see it in the screenshots.

Comment: Also you didn't spell out the table names in your screenshots. Could you update your question to incldue the table names above the screenshots?

Comment: I've updated my question with including a new picture and the names of the tables.

Comment: @user2379123 Please select one of the very similar answers to put closure to your question, if either or both answers helped you. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
select m.PNR, m.Name
from Mitarbeiter m
inner join Station s on s.PNR = m.PNR
inner join Pfleger p on p.StationID = s.StationID
where
  m.Ort = 'Frankfurt'
  and p.Name = 'Onkologie'
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on provided table names and column names for tables.

Notice: we eliminated the `,` notation after mitarbeiter, in your base query.

I don't see PNR in mitabeiter  so I'm assuming stationID is how they join.

```
SELECT * 
FROM pfleger P
INNER JOIN Station S
 on S.StationId = P.StationID
INNER JOIN mitarbeiter M
 on M.pnr = S.pnr
WHERE M.ORT='Frankfurt' and P.name = 'Onkologie'
```

Assumptions I made:
pfleger.stationID has a foreign key relationship to station.stationID
mitarbeiter.PNR has a foreign key relationship to station.PNR

We used inner joins here as we only want Mitarbeiter who exist in all 3 tables.
Otherwise we could use outer joins and return those who don't have records as well. (meaning it is unknown where they work it MIGHT be 'Onkologie' but we don't know as there is no record.)

Comment: @user2379123 updated response based on updated screenshots/table names.